# redirect with javascript to another domain with Json

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm retrieving an url from a php file with Json , and then in the success part I do

```
window.location=msg.message
```

but the proble is that if we suppose my domain is http example.com and the 
`msg.message` value is

```
https://otherdomain.com
```

the redirection is done to http:/example.com/https:/otherdomain.com
how can I go directly to https:/otherdomain.com
code

```
     $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (msg){
        $.fn.colorbox.close();//close the box
        alert(decodeURI(msg.message));//
        window.location.href(msg.message); // goes to domain.com/msg.message        
      },
   });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5mWV/1/

(using `window.top` since jsfiddle uses iframes)  Can you post more code?

Comment: `https:/otherdomain.com` should be `https://otherdomain.com`

Comment: I figured out the problem but not the solution ! 
the problem is json_encode , encodes the // and : to %2F%2F and %3A
How can I retrieve the correct url ?

Comment: I Added the code portion, the problem is within the last line

Comment: Ok Guys! I figured this out , I used
unsecape with msg.message

Answer (score 0):

Please use assign method:

```
window.location.assign("https://otherdomain.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **two** stashes before the host part of the URL.

```
https://otherdomain.com
```

You have only one (`https:/otherdomain.com`).

(And `href` is a string, not a function, assign a value to it as you do in the first code block, don't try to call it as you do in the third).

Comment: No , it's stupid but because the stupid reputation system , I couldn't add more than 2 urls in my post.. 
anyways I figured out the problem , I needed to unescape the returned url